# Ad failed to load

Tags: java, android, admob, ads

Не запускается баннер рекламы...

Вот логи:

```
2019-06-28 14:33:48.093 26984-26984/com.anntoxa.foodforyou I/Ads: Updating ad debug logging enablement.
2019-06-28 14:33:48.115 26984-26984/com.anntoxa.foodforyou I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("A2AA9C5E18C297BBCC0AFCF352517EB7") to get test ads on this device.
2019-06-28 14:33:48.348 26984-27346/com.anntoxa.foodforyou W/Ads: Update ad debug logging enablement as false
2019-06-28 14:33:50.768 3278-25975/? I/Ads: SDK version: afma-sdk-a-v16187999.13000000.1
2019-06-28 14:33:50.934 26984-26984/com.anntoxa.foodforyou I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3
```

А тест реклама запускается...

Comment: ошибка не информативна

Comment: Ad failed to load : 3 = NO_FILL.

Comment: @pavel я не много не понял...

Comment: это значит что не пришла реклама

Comment: Обычно нужно пару часов-дней, чтобы не тестовая реклама начала показываться на свежесозданных баннерах.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код 3 означает ошибку NO_FILL. Этой ошибки можно не бояться, она возникает в двух случаях:

1. Вы недавно подрубили рекламу, она начинает показываться не сразу.
2. Просто нету рекламодателя на данную страну на текущий момент, чтобы что-то показать.

Второй пункт, насколько я знаю, в случае тестовой рекламы не актуален.